Triggering Amstrad BASIC/System errors from machine code
I'm writing some machine code that's intended to be executed from BASIC with a CALL and I'd like to trigger genuine errors just like running ERROR 5 (Improper argument) from BASIC.
I have the book The Ins and Outs of the Amstrad by Don Thomasson and I've looked at the jumpblock entries, but I didn't find it there.
How can I trigger errors from machine code that can be caught and handled by a BASIC program using ON ERROR GOTO?

I flipped briefly through the book, but didn't see anything. It wouldn't surprise me at all if it isn't easily done. It seems to me that the intent would have been that one writes a BASIC wrapper function for machine code that handles details like parameter validation and returned error codes.

It can probably be done by calling an appropriate location in ROM, but because the firmware does not provide a stable entry point for those features, the location in the ROM will depend on which version of the CPC the code runs (464, 664/6128, maybe plus machines are again different). Are you targeting a specific machine of do you wish your code to work on any CPC model?

Here's a working solution, assuming you have identified which ROM the machine has:
; Assuming the wished error code is in register A
ld hl, # 0xCB55   ; for a 6128 or plus, or 0xCA93 for a 464 or 0xCB58 for a 664
ld c,  # 0xFD     ; means enable only upper ROM
jp     0x1B       ; see Soft968 section 18 e.g. https://www.cpcwiki.eu/imgs/7/7f/S968se18.pdf page 18.13

Here's a BASIC program using that.
10 memory &7FFF
20 load"asm2err"
30 on error goto 200
40 for i%=0 to 33
50 if i%=31 then print "== Errors 31 and above are custom. =="
60 print "Error";i%;"... ";
70 call &8000,i%
80 next
90 list
200 print "caught";ERR;"on line";ERL : resume next

A fully working solution, including auto-detection of ROM version is here on Github. Tested on emulated 464/664/6128/Plus. You can run it (on a Linux machine) with:
git clone https://github.com/cpcitor/asm2err
cd asm2err
make

Here are screenshots:


For easy reference, you also have the list of built-in errors in the manual e.g. page 338 ("chapter 7 page 27") and discussed on sean.co.uk/books/amstrad/amstrad1.shtm

Very cool! Not Code Golf, but I shaved a byte off your asm code and made it imperceptibly faster! I moved the calling code to the start and replaced ld hl, 0x0000 with jr configure, nop. Then I changed the self-modifying code to ld de, where_hl_is_set, ld a, 0x21, ld (de), a, inc de, ldi, ldi, pop de, jr where_hl_is_set.

@CJDennis yes, Code Golfing it as much as you want is welcome, even offer a pull request. I pushed a slightly shorter version by using a firmware call to enable upper ROM instead of doing it by hand, saves 9 bytes.

I have simplified code further. Given the BASIC context only optimizing for size should count. From the initial 58 bytes it comes down to 22 bytes. See https://github.com/cpcitor/asm2err/blob/master/asm2err.s
